# How to make Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 13.10 dual-boot correctly?

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

My computer has two HDDs, one has 2T(Disk 1) while the other one has 500G(Disk 2). First I installed Windows 8.1 on disk1 and everything went well. Next I installed Ubuntu 13.10 desktop by a USB stick. I performed disk partition on disk2 manually and this is the partitions on disk2:

```
/dev/sdb1 | /boot | primary
/dev/sdb2 | /     | primary
/dev/sdb5 | /swap | logical
/dev/sdb6 | /home | logical
```

I placed boot loader on /dev/sdb1 and then installation went on. After finishing copying files, the computer restarted and booted from HDD instead of USB stick. However, when I set the boot device as disk 1 I could enter Windows 8.1 but when I set disk2 as boot device I got GRUB problem reminding me of a device not found, entering GRUB rescue mode. I want to know what happened to Ubuntu installation and what can I do now.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem - you need to install GRUB to the drive, not to a partition.

I re-installed Ubuntu on disk2 and put boot loader on **/dev/sdb** instead of **/dev/sdb1**. Then I booted the computer from disk2 and then I could see the boot menu including "Ubuntu" and "Windows Recovery Environment".